# How to Log out from twitter on an android app

Tags: android, twitter, logout

Here is the code that I am using to remove data that twitter uses to log me in so as to create a log out button. But it still logging me automatically. Any ideas?

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = (this.getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFERENCES,
Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).edit();
    editor.remove(Login.userkey);
    editor.remove(Login.usersecret);
    editor.remove(Login.username);
    editor.commit();
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implement the twitter using the http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/ . so i can logout using the

```
 public void logoutTwitter() {
        mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
    }
```

Please check the code on the site and also check the GitHub.

I hope this will help you.